# Do something right before close the program

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a perl program, using Tk. Is there any option to create a kind of "destructor" of a perl script? I mean for example I'd like to close a database, and kill a child process, before   the main window closes.

Comment: `END { ... }` perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

You can use an [`END` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END)

```
END { 
  print "before exit\n";
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `END` block is executed _after_ the main window closes. But for killing child processes, closing databases etc. this is good enough. For Perl/Tk there are also other possibilities (`OnDestroy`, `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`, executing something after the `MainLoop` call...).

Comment: @erbal you can accept answer by clicking on the left part of the answer if it works for you.